# pdftk killing my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdftk

I have a PDF that uses JavaScript to print as soon as it gets opened. I need to remove certain pages. However, the output that `pdftk` produces no longer has the JavaScript that makes it print when it gets opened. Is there any way to preserve JS with a pdftk-processed file?

I'm not 100% tied to pdftk, but whatever alternative I choose needs to run from the command line in Linux and be capable of removing pages. Just for reference, this is how I'm using pdftk:

`pdftk infile.pdf cat 2-end output outfile.pdf`

Comment: I found [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) and it works perfectly with no extra effort. Fortunately it's free because the site I'm using it for is non-commercial (and I'm not getting paid to create it). In case you're interested, here is the command: `cpdf infile.pdf 2-end -o outfile.pdf`